# Have mc show size, time and permissions at once

Tags: mc

Simple question: How can I set up `mc` (midnight commander) to show columns for the file name, size, time *and* permissions all at once? I can cycle through 4 modes with Alt+T but none of them shows all desired data and still two panels side by side. Is this even possible? I'd be surprised if it wasn't. Every Windows file manager lets me precisely select the columns to show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> or click on the top menu bar, go to `Left` > `Listing format` and set `User defined` text field to

```
half type name | size | mtime | perm
```

On the listing format dialog you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to find the meaning of those tokens. A similar and more succint alternative is

```
half type name | bsize:4 | mtime | mode:3
```

Repeat the steps for the `Right` panel if you want both panels with the same format.

Below is the view obtained by setting the left panel to the first option and the right panel to the second one.

[image: Sample view of the two panels]